# How to prevent an invalid value when inline editing a data table in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am inline editing a data table. The value being edited should be lower than the value in another column. How can I prevent an invalid value to be entered?

[image]

```
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.code }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.itemName }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.price }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.amount }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right red lighten-3">
        <v-edit-dialog
          :return-value.sync="props.item.returnAmount"
          large
          lazy
          @save="saveLine(props.item)"
          persistent
          saveText="Guardar"
          cancelText="Cancelar"
        >
          <div class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.returnAmount }}</div>
          <template v-slot:input>
            <div class="mt-3 title">Actualizar Ctd a Devolver</div>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:input>
            <v-text-field
              v-model="props.item.returnAmount"
              :rules="returnAmountRules"
              type="number"
              label="cantidad a devolver"
              autofocus
            ></v-text-field>
          </template>
        </v-edit-dialog>
      </td>
    </template>
```

I created a validation rule **returnAmountRules** to signal as an error if a negative amount is entered.
I also created a method **saveLine** to validate that the **return amount** is not larger than the **amount** column.

The returnAmountRules display an error, but allow entering a negative amount
In the saveLine method I can compare the values...but then what?

Ideally I should be able to prevent the user for entering a negative return amount or a return amount that exceeds the original amount.

Thanks

*** EDIT July 3rd, 2019 ***
There is no need for all the hassle below. You can specify a parameter for the rule so I send the whole line as a parameter. 
Change the rules property to:

```
:rules="[returnAmountRules(props.item)]"
```

No need for the currentRow now

*** EDIT ***

I did not find a way to prevent an invalid value to be entered but in the end what I needed was to prevent the submission of invalid values. So I solved this by adding the validation logic used for forms:

1. I added a validation to each row of the data table by adding a **tr** tag and using **@click** to store the values in a data property (currentRow)
2. I added a validation rule to the return amount field (using currentRow to get the values from the other columns)
3. Finally, I surrounded the data table with a  and before submitting the values I called the form validation

   ```
   <v-form ref="devolucionesForm">
   <v-data-table
     :headers="headers"
     :items="devolucionForEditDetails"
     :loading="loading"
     class="elevation-1"
     :no-data-text="noData"
   >
     <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
       <tr @click="selectRow(props.item)">
         <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.code }}</td>
         <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.itemName }}</td>
         <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.price }}</td>
         <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.amount }}</td>
         <td class="text-xs-right">
           <v-text-field
             v-model="props.item.returnAmount"
             type="number"
             :rules="[returnAmountRules]"
           ></v-text-field>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </template>
   </v-data-table>
   ```

```
 data() {
   return {
    ...
    currentRow: {}
   }
 },
 methods: {
    returnAmountRules(v) {
      if (v === undefined) {
        return true
      }

      let returnAmount = parseInt(v, 10)
      let purchaseAmount = parseInt(this.currentRow.amount, 10)

      if (returnAmount < 0) {
        return 'La cantidad no puede ser negativa'
      }

      if (returnAmount > purchaseAmount) {
        return 'La cantidad a devolver no puede ser mayor a la cantidad de compra'
      }

      return true
    },

    selectRow(row) {
      this.currentRow = row
    },

    closeDialog() {
      this.$store.commit('toggleOrdersDialog', {
        editMode: false,
        order: {}
      })
    },
    totalAsCurrency(total) {
      return formatter.format(total)
    },

    solicita() {
      console.log('validate', this.$refs.devolucionesForm.validate())
      let errors = []
      this.devolucionForEditDetails.forEach((elem, i) => {
        if (elem.returnAmount > elem.amount) {
          errors.push(
            `La cantidad a devolver por ${
              elem.returnAmount
            } en la partida ${i} es mayor a la cantidad comprada`
          )
        }
        console.log('Errors', errors)
      })

      this.closeDialog()
    }
  },
```